# How to clone git repository only once in Google Colab

Tags: git, google-colaboratory

I have `git clone` command at the begging of my **Google Colab** notebook and it takes some time for cloning. I use data from that cloned repository further in my notebook.

So, how not to clone the git repository every time I reload the notebook to use the data from it (maybe save repository content somewhere in the google drive??)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which command you are using in your notebook, but I am using the following strategy:

```py
!git clone -l -s https://github.com/covid19-tomography-analysis/utils utils
%cd utils
import plot_images
```

That way, I can import my python functions. Whenever I run this command in a Google Colab notebook, a folder is created in my Google Drive in the same folder where my notebooks are saved.

Perhaps the same is happening to you, but you are not aware of?

After cloning you can just `%cd` to the folder you cloned and use it as you wish, no need to cloning again.